# how can i get the database details from another php file?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Please let me know how i can get `config/database.php` file in Laravel

For exam :  i have file called `test.php` in `root` folder i want the database, host,user and password name from `config/database.php`.How can i acheive this ?

```
'connections' => array(

'mysql' => array(
    'driver'    => 'mysql',
    'host'      => '*********',
    'database'  => '********',
    'username'  => '********',
    'password'  => '*******',
    'charset'   => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    'prefix'    => '',
),
),
```

Comment: downvoters answer this question

Comment: a question. why you need that? (i didn't downvote btw).

Comment: Hey! Have answered your question. Please do checkout

Answer (score 5):

To get the database connection parameters (server, username, password etc) if you're using MySQL, you can do this:

```
echo "Driver: " . Config::get('database.connections.mysql.driver') . "<br/>\r\n";
echo "Host: " . Config::get('database.connections.mysql.host') . "<br/>\r\n";
echo "Database: " . Config::get('database.connections.mysql.database') . "<br/>\r\n";
echo "Username: " . Config::get('database.connections.mysql.username') . "<br/>\r\n";
echo "Password: " . Config::get('database.connections.mysql.password') . "<br/>\r\n";
```

On my local development machine this gives:

> Driver: mysql
>
> Host: localhost
>
> Database: local_dev_db
>
> Username: root
>
> Password: not-my-real-pwd

...obviously you should never show your password (or any of these other details) in your live app! But if it's just for your information on a local development machine you should be fine.

If you're not using MySQL, just replace mysql with sqlite or pgsql or whatever.

Comment: ` Class 'Config' not found in ` where i need to add this class ajay23romu

Comment: where i need to add this ?

Comment: I hope you know how to use the composer in laravel application. Or else chk the link it has installation guide. Follow that.

Comment: so i need to install it again ?

Comment: I hope you understand what i just said, then why this question ? Install it and check. If laravel-debugbar package is already installed, you dont have to install again.

Answer (score 1):

Try it

Write below code in you `test.php` file

```
$config  =(include './app/config/database.php');

$default_database = $config['default'];
$database_config = $config['connections'][$default_database];

echo "host = ".$database_config['host']."<br>";
echo "database = ".$database_config['database']."<br>";
echo "username = ".$database_config['username']."<br>";
echo "password = ".$database_config['password']."<br>";
```

**OUTPUT**

> host = localhost
>
> database = test
>
> username = root
>
> password = 123456

I hope, You are satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

In laravel 5 you can get these details with this command `DB::connection()->getConfig("password")`

BTW Laravel connects to the database for you already. There is no need in application to explicitly get these details and connect yourself.

Comment: how can i access in my file without adding classes ?